# How to use checkboxes in Django Admin for a ManyToMany field through a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'll make a quick resume so you can understand better the structure:

The **Cars** can be driven by different **drivers** and these drivers can get **trophies**. Trophies must be associated to the drivers and to the car they used.

```py
class CarDriver(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('Driver', null=False)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', null=False)
    trophies = models.ManyToManyField('Trophy', blank=True)


class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    drivers = models.ManyToManyField(Driver, blank=True, through=CarDriver)


class Trophy(models.Model):
    position = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

**I want to display the model Car in Django Admin but using a list of checkboxes to select the drivers, so the driver selection will be way faster than using inlines**:

```py
class CardDriverInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CarDriver


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CardDriverInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

Is there a way to use checkboxes for multiple driver selection?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models), when you use a **through** argument to a **ManyToManyField**, the admin will not display a widget by default.

So, in this case you **must** use inlines, unfortunately.

However, if you don't use a *through* argument, you can simply have a **ModelAdmin** like this:

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
```

This way you have the checkboxes, but you lose the trophies reference.

I know, it isn't a fair world. I thought it would exist another way, but the Django docs is clear about why you have to use inlines with the **through** argument.